# How do I search for Value on sheet 2 then if true, multiplying to by a number on the same row?

Tags: excel, if-statement, copy, row, vlookup

I've got a massive table on sheet 2, which has years left on a lease and average values. 
i.e.

```
Years 80  Average(A)97.50% Aver(B)97.09%   Aver(C)96.00% Aver(D)96.00% Aver(D)97.00% Overall Average 96.72%
```

in Sheet 1, cell `C11` has the value of years (this is variable from 80 to 0 - Column A of sheet 2)

I need Cell `E24` (in sheet 1) to automatically copy the overall average figure (96.72% in this case)

is there any way in which I can type in the number of years in `C11` and in `E24` it will;
Search Sheet2 for corresponding years (in Column A -n.b. I've attempted VLOOKUP with no success), then copy the value for the overall average into `E24`?

I have considered adding an extra step where it the value (80 years) is read on `C11`, then on `F11` if it can copy the entire row from sheet 2 for that corresponding value.
Then I can just use simple functions to carry out the calculation from `L11`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are two or three other functions besides Vlookup that you should look at. I don't know the exact layout of your spreadsheet, but let me try here.
1) If you are typing in a value like "80" and you want the corresponding "80th entry in a list" then you use "INDEX" i.e. =INDEX(Sheet2!B2:B82,Sheet1!D21) 
2) If you want to find a value in a list based on another searching column i.e. find the value "80" first in some list of values then find the corresponding average from some other matching list, then you use "INDEX" and "MATCH" together. Match searches for a value and INDEX retrieves. i.e =INDEX(Sheet2!B2:B82, MATCH(Sheet1!D21, SHEET2!A2:A82,0))